# Checkbox and page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have an asp.net CheckBox, now I want to reload page after check or uncheck and use CheckBox.Checked information to choose sql query for gridview. I have put code like this in Page_Load method:

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked)
{
    query = "select ...";
}
```

But nothing happen. I set AutoPostBack also. Tried to use event. Don;t know how this system works:/

EDIT:
Checkbox works ok, but the problem is in something different. After I click checkbox, in Page_Load method I will use my query to setup SqlDataSource. Looks like page is reloaded, but gridview is not refreshed. When i click on gridview's column mame (to sort this column), gridview is refreshed by new sql query. So i need to think how to refresh grid view after click check box.

Comment: When you click your check box does the Page_load event even get hit?

Comment: please update your answer with the checkbox instantiation code and the function where the Checkbox1.Checked code is located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are not using `IsPostBack` property on page load event. If you not use this your `CheckBox` will be reset on every page load

Try this way

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Here do your stuff.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Combined IsPostBack with GridView.DataBind and it works perfectly.